# Adding custom card elements into the adaptive-card-designer

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

[Debugger console showing progressbar successfully added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fboaE.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility

This documentation shows an example to show a progress bar and create your own action
But how do I then show those in the designer ? Where can I find documentation for the same?

For the ProgressBarPeer, this is my class type : export class ProgressBarPeer extends ACDesigner.TypedCardElementPeer

This is what I sent to registerPeer : ACDesigner.CardDesignerSurface.cardElementPeerRegistry.registerPeer(
ProgressBar,
ProgressBarPeer,
"Elements",
'acd-icon-columnSet'
);
If I use AC.TextBlock instead of my own custom component ProgressBar I do see changes in the properties as defined in my ProgressBarPeer

Please let me know what maybe missing to see the ProgressBar under elements in the designer. I am using all the latest npm packages.
I am attaching as evidence my registry that contains an action and an element with their peers.
It would be great if there was some more documentation and an example for adding an action and an element to the designer. Thanks.

Following : https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/discussions/5240

@matthidinger @dclaux